# Positiveness of a specified quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

The condition of the positiveness of a ordinary quadratic form can be derived by getting the condition of positiveness of a square matrix, like  ${v}^{T}{A}{v} \geq 0$ is equal to matrix $A \geq 0$ where $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

And what is the condition of positiveness if vector $v$ has a specified form?

If $v = [x^2\quad y^2\quad z^2]$ and $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$, my question is what condition matrix $A$ should satisfy so that a quadratic form, $v^{T}Av$, is positive $\forall x,y,z 
\in \mathbb{R}$?

And I think in this case, matrix $A$ does not have to be positive to make this specified quadratic form positive. Positiveness of matrix $A$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition. I was wondering if there is a necessary and sufficient condition for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You mixed the words necessary and sufficient.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Positiveness of matrix $A$ is a **sufficient condition**, but not **necessary**

Comment: Actually I am thinking the opposite way that if the statement is true, positiveness of matrix $A$ can not be derived. Opposite direction, positiveness of matrix $A$ can derive the statement.

Comment: Okay, it's clear what you *think* those words mean, but they mean the opposite. $A\geq 0$ is *enough* to guarantee the inequality holds, so positivity is a *sufficient* condition. However, if the condition holds, it is not *necessary* that we have $A\geq 0$.

Comment: I was wondering if you have any idea about what is the sufficient and necessary condition is? Positiveness of matrix $A$ is not good enough for me to narrow the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that we can find only sufficient conditions for matrix $A$.

If we set $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\ A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33}\end{bmatrix} $, then we have:

$v^T A v= x^4A_{11} + y^4A_{22} + z^4A_{33} + x^2y^2(A_{21} + A_{12}) + x^2z^2(A_{13} + A_{31}) + y^2z^2(A_{23} + A_{32})\tag{1},$

where $v^T = [ x^2 \quad y^2 \quad z^2]$.

---

**Some sufficient conditions for matrix $A$, so that $v^T A v \ge 0$**:

- $A$ has all its elements non - negative.
- $A$ is positive semidefinite.
- $A$ is a skew-symmetric-like matrix with non - negative diagonal elements.

From $(1)$ we can easily figure out that if $A$ is a skew-symmetric-like matrix (which means $A_{ij} = -A_{ij}, \forall i\neq j$), then $$v^T A v = x^4A_{11} + y^4A_{22} + z^4A_{33}.$$ So, we can conclude that if all the diagonal elements are non-negative, then $v^TAv \ge 0,\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And If $A$ is skew symmetric matrix, $A_{11}, A_{22}$ and $A_{33}$ would be zero.

Comment: Does your last statement  hold true only for skew symmetric matrix $A$ or any square matrix $A$. If only for skew symmetric matrix $A$, $v^{T}Av$ is equal to zero instead of $\geq 0$.

Comment: If $A$ is skew symmetric matrix, $A_{11}, A_{22}, A_{33} $ are equal to zero, and they can not be positive numbers.

Comment: Oops, you are right. I focused on the off-diagonal elements. In any case, you can consider a matrix $A$, which is "almost" skew-symmetric, with $A_{ij} = -A_{ji}, \forall i\neq j$.

Comment: I think for skew symmetric the quadratic form is always zero.

Comment: Yeap, it seems so.